# How to prevent breaking MVC routes when changing the name of a method in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, routes

I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent errors that could come from renaming a method inside a Controller of an MVC app.

Let's say I have a route defined as

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RouteName",
    url: "some/url",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Edit" }
    );
```

And `MyController` looks like this:

```cs
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;        

    public MyController(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(decimal value)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

In this case, if I rename the method named "Edit" to say "EditUser", the route will be broken, but there will be no compile error to let me know. Is there a way to make this more robust?

For the controller name it's easier since we can use typeof(MyController) and strip the part ending with "Controller", but I can't seem to find a clean way to get the method name.

I tried to use something like this, but then I would need a version of this for all possible number of arguments.

```cs
    public static string GetMethodName<T1, TResult>(Func<T1, TResult> method)
    {
        return method.Method.Name;
    }
```

With the route specified as :

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RouteName",
    url: "some/url",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "MyController", 
        action =  GetMethodName<decimal, ActionResult>(new MyController(null).Edit);
        }
    );
```

So, it does work, but then I need a different overload for methods that takes a different number of arguments. (Eg. <T1, T2, TResult>, <T1, T2, T3, TResult>, etc.)

Is there a way to combine these overloads or a cleaner way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This is actually 2 questions. How to let compiler handle the name relationships? -> `nameof(MyController.Edit)`. How to bind overloads? -> no idea, hope someone else answers. I personally don't overload endpoints at controller layer, instead I create 1 method with optional parameters, or optional fields in the request class. Keep it simple and one place, otherwise when debugging you'd not only need to know the path to trace up the code, but also need to compare request content to find the correct overload. This is personal opinion though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the specific method route, why don't you use the dynamic routing in-built with MVC.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RouteName",
            url: "some/url",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

This way it will automatically pick the actionName from your url.
This way your url `xyz.com/My/Edit` will redirect to `Edit` ActionMethod and if you use `xyz.com/My/EditUser` it will redirect to `EditUser` ActionMethod.

Alternatively you can use actionName which will override the default.

```
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit / EditUser(int id)
{
    // both will redirect to YourControllerName/Edit
    return View();
}
```

but you have to keep in mind only one ActionName can exist within a controller.

Comment: I'm working with legacy stuff and can't really change the URL in this case unfortunatly.

Comment: For that you can use action Method Name as I have edited in my answer.